# I have 88 rows in my db i am retrieving from the db, i want them to display them in three columns in php mysql

Tags: php, database

I have 88 rows in my db i am retrieving from the db, i want them to display them **in three columns like 32,30,26** like this , can u pls help me how to do this. 32,30,30 are the number of rows that each column should have

Comment: What have you done so far? What is the table structure?

Comment: What have you tried? How do you retrieve the data from the db? - And what do you want to display in three columns? The (presumably) three fields of each row? Or do you want to display one row in each column?

Comment: I used the limit 1,30,limit 30,60,and 60,80  in the sql query....  so far the values are retriving but not coming properly

Answer (score 1):

If you want even columns, it will be easier to do (I cannot really understand hoe you came to 32,30,26) But you could do something like this:

```
$counter=1;
echo "<table><tr>"
while($row=someFetchFromDatabase($result))
{
    echo "<td>$row['col1']</td>";
    $counter++;
    if($counter%3==0)
    {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

This will increment a counter and display three rows until the end of the dataset - though you should add to the solution here to clean up the details.

Comment: This is good but will display results from left to right and then top to bottom. My version below should fill the left column first before subsequent columns. If you (@Siva Shanker) had been specific with your question you could have saved one of us some wasted time!

Comment: @cronoklee Yeah, it seems so. The question was rather vague. +1 to your answer anyhow, it seems very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of results `mysql_num_rows()`, divide by 3. In your php loop, add a counter. When it hits the result of the division, move onto the next column. Something like this:

```
$third = mysql_num_rows($sqlresult)/3;
$counter=1;
echo "<div>";
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult)){
    if($counter++ > $third){
        $counter = 1;
        echo "</div><div>";
    }
    echo $r[0]."<br />";
}
echo "</div>";
```

You could also change the divs to tds and trs if you are using tables or remove the markup and use commas as you have done in your question

Comment: I am tempted to vote +1 for the literal interpretation of the question. But do you have reason to believe that this is actually the desired behaviour?

Comment: No, it's a poorly phrased question so I'm making some assumptions